# Rails per-request hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to cache per-request data in Rails?  For a given Rails/mongrel request I have the result of a semi-expensive operation that I'd like to access several times later in that request.  Is there a hash where I can store and access such data?

It needs to be fairly global and accessible from views, controllers, and libs, like Rails.cache and I18n are.

I'm ok doing some monkey-patching if that's what it takes.

- Memcached doesn't work because it'll be shared across requests, which I don't want.
- A global variable similarly doesn't work because different requests would share the same data, which isn't what I want.
- Instance variables don't work because I want to access the data from inside different classes.

Comment: You say you want it to be shared across requests (bullet 1), but also that you don't want requests sharing it (bullet 2). I think I know what you mean, but you should clarify.

Comment: In bullet 1 I say I _don't_ want it shared across requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [PerRequestCache](http://gist.github.com/177780). I stole the design from the SQL Query Cache.

Configure it up in `config/environment.rb` with:

```
config.middleware.use PerRequestCache
```

then use it with:

```
PerRequestCache.fetch(:foo_cache){ some_expensive_foo }
```

Comment: As your gist suggests, it's not thread-safe.   I just ended up stashing stuff directly in the SQL Query Cache.  It's a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

There is also the [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem. From the documentation:

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'request_store'
```

and use this code to store and retrieve data (confined to the request):

```
# Set
RequestStore.store[:foo] = 0

# Get
RequestStore.store[:foo]
```

Comment: The gem basically solves the entire problem. I've added in some usage instructions, but basically there isn't much more to it than that.

Comment: You shouldn't use this gem with a threaded server like Thin or Puma.

Comment: @Papipo The documentation for this gem explicitly defines itself as a functional alternative to `Thread.current` for threaded servers like Thin and Puma.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most popular options is to use the [`request_store`](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem, which allows you to access a global store that you from any part of your code. It uses `Thread.current` to store your data, and takes care of cleaning up the data after each request.

```
RequestStore[:items] = []
```

Be aware though, since it uses `Thread.current`, it won't work properly in a multi-threaded environment where you have more than one thread per request.

To circumvent this problem, I have implemented a store that can be shared between threads for the same request. It's called [`request_store_rails`](https://github.com/ElMassimo/request_store_rails), it's thread-safe, and the usage is very similar:

```
RequestLocals[:items] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered flash? It uses Session but is automatically cleared.

Answer (score 0):

[Memoisation](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/16/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-memoization)?

According to [this railscast](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/137_memoization.mov) it's stored per request.

Comment: Memoisation on the class method will cache for all time. Memoisation on an instance will cache for the lifetime of that instance. Excessive caching on classes clogs up memory. I've taken down production boxes making this mistake.

Answer (score -2):

Global variables are evil.  Work out how to cleanly pass the data you want to where you want to use it.

Comment: That's not always practical.  Like I mentioned, Rails has globalish objects like Rails.cache and I18n.

Answer (score -3):

**app/models/my_cacher.rb**

```
class MyCacher
  def self.result
    @@result ||= begin
      # do expensive stuff
      # and cache in @@result
    end
  end
end
```

The ||= syntax basically means "do the following if @@result is nil" (i.e. not set to anything yet).  Just make sure the last line in the begin/end block is returning the result.

Then in your views/models/whatever you would just reference the function when you need it:

```
MyCacher.result
```

This will cache the expensive action for the duration of a request.

Comment: This will be cached for the lifetime of the app instance (many requests) in production mode.